# I can't manage files from s3 using ansible aws_s3 module

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, boto3, botocore

Running the following task on my playbook:

```
- name: "Check if hold file exists..."
  amazon.aws.aws_s3:
    region: <region>
    bucket: <bucket>
    prefix: "hold_jobs_{{ env }}"
    mode: list
  register: s3_files
```

I Got the following error:

```
{
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload_b92r42e3/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/aws_s3.py\", line 427, in bucket_check\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n  File \"/var/lib/awx/venv/ansible/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 661, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\nbotocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Bad Request\n",
    "boto3_version": "1.9.223",
    "botocore_version": "1.12.253",
    "error": {
        "code": "400",
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
```

I am using this configuration:

```
    ansible [core 2.11.7]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /var/lib/awx/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
  jinja version = 2.10.1
  libyaml = True
```

I need help to solve this, thanks in advance. For this moment I am using a paliative solution, with shell module.

Comment: Hi Kaike Iaralian welcome to SO. I _think_ a 400 for `HeadBucket` is due to using the wrong region for the bucket; `aws s3` will automatically redirect when it knows the bucket is wrong, but "pure" botocore might not do that, choosing to `raise` instead. Have you confirmed the region is correct?

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, I am using the correct region that is sa-east-1.